# Getting an error "failed to compile Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader"

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue2-google-maps

Im using vue to import google maps to my application

but it does not let me run my application once i import it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from "vue2-google-maps";

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: "",
    libraries: "places" // necessary for places input
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and this is the error im getting

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/temporary/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/infoWindow.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/Users/temporary/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components'
 @ /Users/temporary/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/components/infoWindow.vue 4:0-161 5:0-174
 @ /Users/temporary/node_modules/vue2-google-maps/dist/main.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `vue-cli` for this project? If so, you should be able to just do:

- `npm install --save-dev babel-loader`

(or if you're using `yarn`)

- `yarn add --dev babel-loader`

If you're not using `vue-cli` then you will still need to install `babel-loader` using the methods above, but you will also have to add it to your `webpack` config.

***More on `babel-loader`:***

- [From the Vue docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#babel)
- [More detailed example of `babel-loader`, `vue`, and `webpack`](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/setting-up-a-vue-project-with-webpack-4-and-babel-7/)
- [Example `webpack` config, taken from the `vue2-google-maps` GitHub repo](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/webpack.config.js)